# POST request fails with missing required Body Aqueduct + PostgreSQL

Tags: dart, post, aqueduct

I'm building my first API with Aqueduct and a PostgreSQL db. To test my endpoint I'm using Postman on the locally running server. GET requests works as expected, but the POST request  fails with missing Body error:

```
{
    "error": "missing required Body ''"
}
```

this is the method:

```
@Operation.post()
  Future<Response> addAlert(@Bind.body(ignore: ['id']) Alert newAlert) async {
    print('incoming alert to save is $newAlert');

    final query = Query<Alert>(context)
    ..values = newAlert;
    final alert = await query.insert();

    // return Response.ok(alert);
    return alert != null
    ? Response.ok(alert)
    : Response.badRequest();
  }
```

and this is the Model:

```
class Alert extends ManagedObject<_Alert> implements _Alert{}

class _Alert {
  @primaryKey
  int id;
  @Column(unique: false)
  String name;
  @Column(unique: false,nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String city;
  @Column(unique: false,nullable:  true, indexed: true)
  String region;
  @Column(unique: false,nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String country;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  int date;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String description;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String alertIcon;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String latitude;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String longitude;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String alertImageName;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String alertImageUrl;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  String userName;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  int utilityPoints;
  @Column(unique: false, nullable: true, indexed: true)
  int votesToDelete;
}
```

In Postman I set the host as `localhost:8888/alerts` as for the Get requests, selected a `Content-Type application/json` header and a `raw JSON` Body which is :

```
{
    "name":"postman",
    "city":"Bologna",
    "region":"Emilia-Romagna",
    "country":"Italy",
    "date":1111111,
    "description":"test",
    "alertIcon":"test",
    "latitude":"11.111",
    "longitude":"22.222",
    "alertImageName":"test",
    "alertImageUrl":"jjj",
    "userName":"user",
    "utilityPoints":1,
    "votesToDelete":1
}
```

Can you spot why is missing the Body?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was a Postman headers setting problem.. I in did only enable `Content-Type application/json and wrongly disabled the others.
They had to be active too and it now works as expected.
Hope this helps others.
Cheers.

[image]